# Microsoft Outlook 2013 not uploading new folders to IMAP

Tags: email, imap, microsoft-outlook-2013

I am using Microsoft Outlook 2013 with IMAP.

I have made many folders in Outlook to archive the e-mails to the right project.
But Outlook isn't uploading these new folders anymore.

When i use Outlook 2007 on a other computer it does work.
So i guess Outlook 2013 is the problem.

There are no sync issues visible, and when i add a folder in the webmail it is being seen in the subscription, but being created in Outlook 2013.

Folders created in 2007 will not appear in outlook 2013, but i can see them in the webmail. Folders made in outlook 2013 will not appear in the webmail or outlook 2007.

How can i force Outlook 2013 to put all folders to the imap account?

Comment: Question: When you create the folders in 2013, they are showing up in 2007 but not the other way around?

Comment: Foldrs created in 2007 will not appear in outlook 2013, but i can see them in the webmail. Folders made in outlook 2013 will not appear in the webmail or outlook 2007

Comment: Did Radu's solution below work for you?

Comment: I did a more dramatic solution. I downgraded from outlook 2013 to 2007. Now everything works fine

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue.

It looks like a folder creation issue (by Outlook 2013).

The work around is to create the folder as well in webmail, and then navigate to the folder in Outlook 2013.  It then commences synchronising the emails it has stored.

I've verified - it pushes the local emails up and doesn't just delete local emails to 'synchronise' the server copy.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem on my account also. The quickest solution that I found was to recreate my email account in Outlook (first be sure to export your rules if you have any).

From what I saw online there are numerous glitches and bugs in Outlook 2013 so this could be one of them.